# "Save As" Dialog in ASP.Net for exporting an excel file? (service account)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, excel-interop

I have a code working for saving the exported file into my PC/Destination however since the ASP.NET (4.0) will be displayed in a server running a service account, i would like to let the user after he clicks the button1 to prompt "Save as" dialog so they can save it in their respective folder (**In the user's PC, not server**). (i can not use environment since it will grab the service account address, since this is in the server its not possible.)

Note: to get the user name i'm using request.servervariables("Logon_User") and did look for some posts here. 
-[Exporting datatable to excel file with save dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430551/exporting-datatable-to-excel-file-with-save-dialog)
-[Export DataGridView To Excel with Save Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402233/export-datagridview-to-excel-with-save-dialog)
-[Dialog Box for Save As location in VBA Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948344/dialog-box-for-save-as-location-in-vba-macro)

```
Dim cnn As SqlConnection
    Dim connectionString As String
    Dim sql As String
    Dim i, j As Integer

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")

    connectionString = "Data Source=xxxx"
    cnn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    cnn.Open()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM ControlCharts"
    Dim dscmd As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    dscmd.Fill(ds)

    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = _
            ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(j)
        Next
    Next

    'here instead of saving it to the C drive, let the user choose.
    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\\ControlCharts.xlsx")
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()
    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
    cnn.Close()
    CheckBox1.Checked = False
```

Comment: That's fundamentally impossible.  The user cannot interact with UI on the server.

Comment: Also, you should not automate Office on a server; it won't work well.

Comment: https://github.com/SLaks/ExcelExporter

Comment: Sorry, i think the question was not clear.. i would like to save as in the User's Desktop not in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the user interact with UI and filesystem on the server.

Instead, you can save the file to a temporary path on the server, then serve it as a file download over HTTP.